# Anagram Sentences

Tags: word, anagram

For each of the below sentences, find a set of anagrams that can fill in the blanks to form a coherent, grammatically correct sentence. See the example below if you don't understand. I won't provide the letter length of each anagram set (at least not yet) but will say that all are in [4,6] letters. I will accept the first answer that finds an anagram set that meets the requirements for each sentence (even if this happens to differ from my intended set, which may well be possible). Have fun and good luck!

> Example Sentence:
>   The `___` is located `___` the `___` on the body.
>   Example Answer:
>   BOWEL, BELOW, ELBOW.
>
> Sentences:
>   The `___`, full of `___` water, `___` for several years before eroding.
>
> In between the first and second `___`, we met the `___` of `___`.
>
> The tailor did amazing work: some `___` and a `___` here and there handled the extra fabric (pardon the occasional and accidental `___`) and a `___` in the mirror revealed a seamless fit.
>
> From the `___`, he sat quiet as a `___` while I played the `___` and `___` of the performance.
>
> He was a `___` of many famous historical `___`, some of whom were even featured on our `___`. (This anagram set contains words of length 5)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The `___`, full of `___` water, `___` for several years before eroding.

> DELTAS, SALTED, LASTED (Thanks alexmc.)
> <strike>LATS, SALT, LAST 
> (Lats are the currency units of Latvia. This sentence is not logical, but forms a coherent grammatical sentence nonetheless.)
>
> KALE, LAKE, LEAK
> (Also not logical, but grammatically correct.)</strike>

> In between the first and second `___`, we met the `___` of `___`.

> ACTS, CAST, CATS

> The tailor did amazing work: some `___` and a `___` here and there handled the extra fabric (pardon the occasional and accidental `___`) and a `___` in the mirror revealed a seamless fit.

> PINS, SNIP, NIPS, SPIN

> From the `___`, he sat quiet as a `___` while I played the `___` and `___` of the performance.

> ONSET, STONE, TONES, NOTES

> He was a `___` of many famous historical `___`, some of whom were even featured on our `___`.

> SCION ICONS COINS (Thanks Simon for the best fit.)
> <strike>MASTER, ARMETS, STREAM (Armets are medieval era helmets.) (Thanks GordonK for the push.)</strike>

Comment: The deltas, full of salted water, lasted for several years before eroding works

Comment: He was a master of many famous historical maters, some of whom were even featured on our stream.

Comment: @GordonK: I had thought of the same initially, but now have a slightly better solution (IMO).

Comment: Not to sound nit-picky, but I believe referring to inanimate objects (armets) as 'whom' constitutes a violation of grammar. My intended set of anagrams is 5 letters long, not 6, if that is helpful.

Comment: @NeedAName, also, you master a sword or other weapon. But I've never heard of mastering a helmet.

Comment: @CodeNewbie as you did the majority of work and have the closest to complete answer, if you'll update the last set of anagrams, I will accept your answer so we can close this one out

Comment: @NeedAName: Completed the answer

Answer (score 17):

I believe this is a better fit for the last one than CodeNewbie's.

> He was a `___` of many famous historical `___`, some of whom were even featured on our `___`.

> SCION ICONS COINS

Comment: Very nice Simon! Hope you enjoyed the healthy boost in rep!

Comment: I don't understand how this ended up with more upvotes than the otherwise complete answer. :P